# Scroll over fixed viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to scroll over fixed viewpager with nested scrollbar. The issue is I am able to scroll content over fixed viewpager but I am unable to swipe viewpager to change product images. I had tried CollapsingToolbar for this but it didn't worked. So I developed another layout which does what I wanted but the thing is it doesn't worked with viewpager.
Here is my current layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.kiranahouse.activity.SingleProductActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:collapseIcon="@drawable/back_colored"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/product_image_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_image_pager">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:id="@+id/pager_tab_layout"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="center">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingTop="250dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#fafafa">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:padding="16dp">
                                <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Product Name"
                                    android:textColor="@color/normalButtonGradientEnd"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                    android:id="@+id/product_title"/>
                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/product_title"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:ellipsize="end"
                                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                        android:text="Rs. 1024"
                                        android:id="@+id/actual_price"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actual_price"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                        android:text="Rs. 2999"
                                        android:id="@+id/old_price"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="28 % Off"
                                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                        android:background="@drawable/discount_single_product"
                                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                                        android:id="@+id/discount_percentage"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/customDividerColor"/>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:scaleX="-1"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:src="@drawable/ic_reply"
                                        android:tint="@color/dividerColor"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>
                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Share"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="1sp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@color/customDividerColor"/>
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:scaleX="-1"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                                        android:tint="@color/dividerColor"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>
                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Wishlist"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="16dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Unit"
                                android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColor"/>
                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="16dp">
                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="600dp">

                            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:radius="0"
            app:startColor="@color/normalButtonGradientStart"
            app:endColor="@color/normalButtonGradientEnd"
            android:text="Add to Cart"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and these are the screenshots I have taken,
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The images and the product's card view are independent of each other? Means if you scroll the product's card view, the image above should not changed/swiped? Am i right?

Comment: @iMDroid yes both the nested scrollview and viewpager are independent I just want the scroll should hide the `viewpager` when it is scrolled and if user swipe through `viewpager` it should change the image. The view pager is changing image if I don't put the `nestedscrollview` the `viewpager` changes images on swipe, if I do put the `nestedscrollview` it scrolls over the `viewpager` but I loose control on swipe of `viewpager`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ViewPager is not working because it's not receiving any touch event as it is behind the RelativeLayout containing NestedScrollView. So better option is to re-design the layout. Like adding both the RelativeLayouts in a FrameLayout and set clipping parameters. Check the code given below. I checked it and it's working as expected.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.kiranahouse.activity.SingleProductActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:collapseIcon="@drawable/back_colored"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/product_image_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_image_pager">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/pager_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="250dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#fafafa"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:padding="16dp">

                                <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/product_title"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:text="Product Name"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                    android:textColor="@color/normalButtonGradientEnd" />

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/product_title"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/actual_price"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:ellipsize="end"
                                        android:text="Rs. 1024"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/old_price"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actual_price"
                                        android:text="Rs. 2999" />

                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/discount_percentage"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:background="@drawable/discount_single_product"
                                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                                        android:text="28 % Off" />

                                </RelativeLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/customDividerColor" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                        android:scaleX="-1"
                                        android:src="@drawable/ic_reply"
                                        android:tint="@color/dividerColor" />

                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Share"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="1sp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@color/customDividerColor" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="8dp">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                        android:scaleX="-1"
                                        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                                        android:tint="@color/dividerColor" />

                                    <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Wishlist"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="16dp">

                            <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomTextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Unit"
                                android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColor" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="16dp">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="600dp">

                            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <org.kiranahouse.component.CustomButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Add to Cart"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:endColor="@color/normalButtonGradientEnd"
            app:radius="0"
            app:startColor="@color/normalButtonGradientStart" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Mohammad Your solution is working but there is one issue the appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is not working the relative layout is scrolling above toolbar.

Comment: Oh that i didn't noticed, i was just checking fixed viewpager swiping & nestedscrollview scrolling above that viewpager. And you better implement this using CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

As stated in the above answer, you have used a nestedscrollview after the view pager with the parent as coordinatorlayout, which will stack the nestedscrollview over the view pager instead of aligning it linearly(as its not a linear layout). Now, giving padding top to the nestedscrollview content and making the view pager under the nestedscrollview visible will not allow you to interact with it as the touch interaction is still with the nestedscrollview's transparent overlay view over the viewpager.

Solution:

The right way to achieve what you want is by using CollapsingToolbarLayout.

1.**Create a CollapsingToolbarlayout inside the appBarLayout, wrap the
 toolbar with the collapsing toolbar layout(i.e Move the toolbar inside the
 collapsing toolbar layout).**

2.Define the fixed height you want for the view pager as the height of
 appbar layout.

3.Give the content scrim color as the color you want for the toolbar when
 the collapsing toolbar collapses instead of giving background color for
 the toolbar.

4.**Move the Relative Layout containing the ViewPager and TabLayout inside
 the CollapsingToolbarLayout, above the toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:contentScrim="#FAFAFA"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/product_image_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_image_pager">
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_layout"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:tabGravity="center">
                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Alternatively you could go with the root as LinearLayout instead of coordinatorlayout.

Though these are the only two right ways to achieve something similar to what you ask for, but if you ask for the view pager to be fixed behind instead of collapsing, then you won't be able to interact with it. In your case fixing a view pager and scrolling content over it doesn't make any sense because anyways you are gonna scroll an entire layout obscuring/hiding the view pager.So using the above solution will emulate the same thing that you would want to achieve using a fixed view pager and an over scroll content.

Comment: @Akashy Moorthy I didn't understand the 4th point you said can you please explain how should I move my relative layout within collapsible toolbar?

Comment: Please see the above code snippet. I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: I had already tried the collapsible toolbar, I want the view pager should not move and according to snippet you have just providing me an example of how can I add viewpager to collapsible toolbar, its not what I am trying to achieve, I want that viewpager should not move

Comment: @VighaneshGursale I guess this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124973/pass-touch-event-from-nestedscrollview-to-parent-views#answer-41139943  is what u r asking for, try this and serif it works, I ll also c if there s any other work around.